# rspec serialized Hash - query empty for records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sqlite

I have a model called Content, with a column called dependencies, serialized as Hash:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dependencies
  serialize :dependencies, Hash
end
```

This really killed my nerves for the last few hours. I'll appreciate any help/hint.

Questions:

- What should be the default (empty) value in migration?
- What should be the default (empty) value in FactoryGirl?
- Most important - how to query in order to find empty values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> What should be the default (empty) value in migration?
>   What should be the default (empty) value in FactoryGirl?

In both cases, the empty hash `{}`

> Most important - how to query in order to find empty values?

Since serialized values are stored using YAML, you need to search as follows:

```
Content.where('dependencies = ?', {}.to_yaml)
```

Here's an irb transcription for my test of the above:

```
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > u = User.new(role: {})
 => #<User id: nil, role: {}, role2: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > u.save
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("role", "role2") VALUES (?, ?)  [["role", "--- {}\n"], ["role2", nil]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > u.role
 => {} 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > {}.to_yaml
 => "--- {}\n" 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > u
 => #<User id: 4, role: {}, role2: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > User.where(role: {}.to_yaml)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."role" = '--- {}
'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 3, role: {}, role2: nil>, #<User id: 4, role: {}, role2: nil>]> 
2.0.0-p247 :007 >
```

(Note: I had created a User instance (#3) prior to posting the first version of this answer, which is why that shows up in my `where` as well).

And here's my `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :who_rated_comment_rels, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
    serialize :role, Hash
    serialize :role2

end
```

You can ignore the stuff not-relevant to your case (i.e. anything other than `role`). I hack on this project for various StackOverflow purposes.

Comment: Migrations can specify default values, by appending :default => value to migration file

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. Could you confirm that it works for you, and if so, your environment?

Comment: Yes, I tested the `where` search I showed, although in my case I didn't restrict the attribute to `Hash`.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could test it with a serialized Hash; it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user1304740 Thanks for confirming the existence of the migration default. I've updated my answer to include evidence of it working for me, using the `Hash` qualifier.

Comment: It surely works under console for me also, but it doesn't work while running a test with rspec. I'm sorry, I should have emphased more that under rspec it doesn't work for me.